# How to Create a VertexBuffer with a Custom Vertex Structure?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a vertex structure:

```
public struct VertexMultitextured
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Normal;
    public Vector4 TextureCoordinate;
    public Vector4 TexWeights;

    public static int SizeInBytes = (3 + 3 + 4 + 4) * sizeof(float);
    public static VertexElement[] VertexElements = new VertexElement[]
 {
     new VertexElement( 0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0 ),
     new VertexElement( sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0 ),
     new VertexElement( sizeof(float) * 6, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0 ),
     new VertexElement( sizeof(float) * 10, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1 ),
 };
}
```

and I would like to create a `VertexBuffer` that uses it.  If I use this line:

`terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, typeof(VertexMultitextured),` 
     `vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);`

I get an error that my structure "does not implement the IVertexType interface," so how do I go about implementing that?  Or is there just an easier way to use this custom struct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. What you've got there looks a bit like the old style for XNA 3.1. The way to do this was improved in XNA 4.0 - [see this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/19/vertex-data-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

Just like the error says, your `VertexMultitextured` needs to implement `IVertexType` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.ivertextype.aspx)), which requires you implement [this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.ivertextype.vertexdeclaration.aspx). Here's what that would look like:

```
public struct VertexMultitextured : IVertexType
{
    // ... all your data members ...

    static readonly VertexDeclaration MyVertexDeclaration
            = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[] {
                // ... your vertex element array ...
            });

    public VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration
    {
        get { return MyVertexDeclaration; }
    }
}
```

(The alternative to implementing the interface is to create the `VertexDeclaration` anywhere, and pass that to the other constructor of `VertexBuffer`.)

You no longer need to keep a reference to your `VertexElement` array around - you can just pass it to the constructor of `VertexDeclaration` and forget about it. You don't need to keep track of the size, either, `VertexDeclaration` will calculate it from your array of elements.

Comment: Oh great! Thank you! Yes, the tutorial I was using was using 3.1 and I was having trouble converting parts of it over (and getting confused about which was which).  That worked perfectly, though, and I got rid of SizeInBytes as you suggested. Thanks again :)